# Can a Tiefling Subrace be Feral?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races, optional-rules, tiefling

*Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* offers the option to select a different heritage for a Tiefling by replacing the default Ability Score Increase with its own (as well as by replacing the Infernal Legacy trait):

> The traits of the chosen subrace replace the tiefling’s Ability Score Increase and Infernal Legacy traits given in the *Player’s Handbook*.

*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* offers variant tieflings by either replacing Infernal Legacy (for Winged, Hellfire, or Devil's Tongue) or by replacing one Ability Score Increase trait with another increasing feature (Feral):

> Feral... This trait replaces the Ability Score Increase trait.

While a non-Asmodeus Tiefling subrace is not compatible with Winged, Hellfire, or Devil's Tongue (since they both replace Infernal Legacy with their own option), a non-Asmodeus Tiefling subrace may be eligible for Feral (by replacing the subrace's own Ability Score Increase with the Feral one). **Is it?**

Comment: I'd assume based on this question and answer, yes: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135045/whats-the-difference-among-feral-tiefling-variant-tiefling-and-variant-feral

Comment: @gabbo1092 that specifically has to do with dndbeyond.com and on D&D Beyond, you *can't* make a Feral Tiefling out of one of the subraces.

Comment: Can you cite the source for Feral?

Comment: @MarkTO It's in the Variant Tiefling section of Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide (end of Chapter 3)

Answer (score 5):

## It's possible with DM permission.

The Feral trait is described as being allowed by DM permission in the sidebar on page 118 of the *Sword Coast Adventurers Guide*, as follows (emphasis mine):

> Since not all tieflings are of the blood of Asmodeus, some have traits that differ from those in the *Player's Handbook*. **The Dungeon Master may permit the following variants for your tiefling character**...

Assuming the DM is open to it, there's no reason that a Levistus Tiefling, for example, doesn't quality as a "tiefling character" for purposes of variant traits including the Feral trait for ability scores. There's nothing in either *SCAG* or *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* that addresses feral tieflings at all beyond that one sidebar, so there's no lore indicating that a non-Asmodeus tiefling can't be feral. All we're told is that the *PHB* tiefling is an Asmodeus Tiefling (this is reinforced in *MTOF* on page 21) and that not all tieflings are of the blood of Asmodeus. It doesn't actually say that the variant options are restricted to non-Asmodeus tieflings, and even if that seems to be implied, note that that passage was written before *MTOF* ever presented any other non-Asmodeus options.

So, with DM permission, the combination should be possible (even though, as I explained in [a related answer to another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/135046/32426), it's not technically possible using D&D Beyond's tools).